# WSO2 API Manager 3.2.0 Registered callback does not match with customUrl behind a proxy

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

The problem I am facing is that after changing the hostname and configuring the reverse proxy as described [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/deployment-best-practices/changing-the-hostname/) and [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/setting-up-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/configuring-the-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/), as well as following the troubleshooting guide [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-invalid-callback-error/) to resolve the 'the registered callback does not match' I am unable to get any further.

I've followed a number of other examples of how to configure nginx and add the reverseProxy property to the settings.js configs but with no luck.

As you can see below if I go to https://example.com/publisher I continue getting the error 'The registered callback does not match'

[image]

Here is what I have the callback regex set to:
regexp=([https://example.com/publisher/services/auth/callback/login|https://example.com/publisher/services/auth/callback/logout](https://example.com/publisher/services/auth/callback/login%7Chttps://example.com/publisher/services/auth/callback/logout))

If I inspect the authorize request query I can see that the redirect_url is being set to 127.0.0.1 and I suspect that is the problem as when I add that url to the service provider regex callback it works, but this is not suitable in a non local environment.

And here is the request query (where I suspect the main issue lies - note redirect_uri):
https://example.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=1obvNiUMBcJwMa3euoHjrsckuGIa&scope=apim:api_create%20apim:api_delete%20apim:api_import_export%20apim:api_product_import_export%20apim:api_publish%20apim:api_view%20apim:app_import_export%20apim:client_certificates_add%20apim:client_certificates_update%20apim:client_certificates_view%20apim:document_create%20apim:document_manage%20apim:ep_certificates_add%20apim:ep_certificates_update%20apim:ep_certificates_view%20apim:external_services_discover%20apim:mediation_policy_create%20apim:mediation_policy_manage%20apim:mediation_policy_view%20apim:pub_alert_manage%20apim:publisher_settings%20apim:shared_scope_manage%20apim:subscription_block%20apim:subscription_view%20apim:threat_protection_policy_create%20apim:threat_protection_policy_manage%20openid&state=/&redirect_uri=https://127.0.0.1/publisher/services/auth/callback/login

Here is how my deployment.toml is configured (I've replaced my actual domain with example.com):
[image: Server]

[image: API Gateway]

Note I had to remove the ports to work behind the proxy
[image: Identity Provider]

[image: Devportal]

[image: Proxy Port]

And here is my settings.js:
I added the reverseProxy property as suggested in a github [issue](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/6808)
[image]

And here is my nginx conf:

[image: Nginx conf]

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error comes down to a missing X-Forwarded-For header, I ended up changing the forwardedHeader in settings.js to Host as that was being passed from my proxy server.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation. Please find the steps to resolve the issue - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-invalid-callback-error/#troubleshooting-registered-callback-does-not-match-with-the-provided-url-error

Comment: Thanks for you're reply, it ultimately came down to the X-Forwarded-For header being missing, for whatever reason my nginx reverse proxy was not adding the header, but I changed the app.customUrl.forwardedHeader to Host as that is being sent by my proxy server

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the detailed question "user3745065".
I was having the exactly same issue you described in this post, and I guess I nailed the problem down.

Like you mentioned the issue is with the forwardedHeader, that in your case you switched to Host.

But checking the product documentation, the sample they provide is the following:

```
customUrl: { // Dynamically set the redirect origin according to the forwardedHeader host|proxyPort combination
enabled: true,
forwardedHeader: 'X-Forwarded-Host',
},
```

It took me a while to noticed that the forwardedHeader is supposed to be 'X-Forwarded-Host' not 'X-Forwarded-For' as it comes as default.

Few other things I needed to tweak that wasn't clear in the documentation for changing the hostname ([here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/deployment-best-practices/changing-the-hostname/)), I had to remove the port variable ${mgt.transport.https.port} from devportal.
That's outlined on the installation step 5 also, [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/install-and-setup/setup/single-node/configuring-a-single-node/). However worth mentioning:

```
from:
[apim.devportal]
url = "https://{Your Domain}:${mgt.transport.https.port}/devportal"
to
url = "https://{Your Domain}/devportal"
```

otherwise  when the it tries to redirect to the portal (for instance, from the publisher) it construct the url with the port number, and that default port 9443 isn't going to work on your proxy (tested on nginx with the provided settings that is on the documentation [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/setting-up-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/configuring-the-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/)) which is listening and expecting calls on port 443.

Things that I noticed you configured but perhaps it's not necessary:

- Set the apim.idp settings
- Set the reverseProxy settings
- Set the apim.gateway.environment settings (Not related to the callback url issue, this is meant for you to configure the runtime gateway urls)

Last but not the least, Following the "[Troubleshooting 'Registered callback does not match with the provided url' error](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-invalid-callback-error/)", again you need to remove the port number from the url, otherwise you will have the same issue aforementioned on your proxy.

Just my 2 cents! ;)

Comment: Thanks for your 2 cents ;)

I did not even notice the incorrect header TBH but Host is working for me so far. I did actually realize that the port needed to be removed at the devportal config as shown in my example config, just forgot to mention it.